# Software that temporarily makes all monitors look more red/orange when you click a button?

Tags: windows, color

1. I don't mean a program that calibrates the monitor.
2. I use a computer monitor + my laptop at the same time
3. I'm looking for a windows desktop program that you click a desktop shortcut and the program puts a  redish/orange translucent rectangle over your monitor and also over your laptop screen, covering all the screen space.
4. If you have used pangobright before, for example, it darkens all monitors + your laptop at the same time by putting a translucent grey color over all the screenspace. I'd like something like that but redish/orange and adjustable how red/how orange for before bedtime falling asleep purposes
5. I already use f.lux. I'm looking for something on top of it. I'm not considering wearing orange tinted sunglasses which could serve the same purpose for a few reasons, but that's outside the topic of software recommendations

I use a windows 10 laptop connected to a monitor